# how to view head of as.data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a huge data set with 20 columns and 20,000 rows, according to the manual of a program I use, we have to put the data as a data frame, though I'm not I understand what it does.. and I can't seem to view the head data frame I created.

I wrote in Bold the part that I don't understand, I'm very new with R, can a kind mind explain to me how the following works?

First I read the CSV file

```
vData = read.csv("my_matrix.csv");
```

1) Here we create the data frame as per the manual, **what does -c(1:8) do exactly??**

```
dataExpr0 = as.data.frame(t(vData[, -c(1:8)]))
```

2) Here, to understand what the above part does, I tried to view only the header of the data frame, with the following line, but it display the first 2 columns for the 20,000 rows of data. **Is there a way to view only the first 2 rows?**

```
head(dataExpr0, n = 2)
```

Comment: head() should display the top rows of the data, not the first columns

Comment: @madkitty, -c(1:8) removes the columns the first 8 columns from your dataframe or matrix. But the issue here is that you have transposed something from 20000 by 12 to 12 by 20000 by using the `t()` function. Because of this, your use of the `head(data, 2)` will generate 2 rows and 20,000 columns. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's disect what your call is doing, from the inside out.

### Basic Indexing

When indexing a `data.frame` or `matrix` (assuming 2 dimensions), you access a single element of it with the square bracket notation, as you're seeing. For instance, to see the value in the fourth row, fifth column, you'd use `vData[4,5]`. This can work with ranges of rows and/or columns as well, such as `vData[1:4,5]` returning the first 4 rows and the 5th column as a vector.

*Note:* the range `1:4` can also be an arbitrary vector of numbers, such as `vData[c(1,2,5),c(4,8)]` which returns a 3 by 2 matrix.

*BTW:* by default, when the resulting slice/submatrix has one of its dimensions reduced to 1 (as in the latter example), *R* will drop it to the lower structure (e.g., `matrix -> vector -> scalar`). In this case, it will drop `vData[1:4,5]` to a vector. You can prevent this from happening by adding what appears to be a third dimension to the square brackets: `vData[1:4,5,drop=FALSE]`, meaning "do not drop the simplified dimension". Now, you should get a matrix of 4 rows and 1 column in return.

You can read a much more thorough explanation of how to subset data.frames by reading (for example) some of the ["Hadleyverse"](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html). If you do that, I highly encourage you to make it an interactive session: play in *R* as you read, to help cement the methods.

### Negative Indexing

Negative indices mean "everything *except* what is listed". In your example, you are subsetting the data to extract everything *except* columns 1:8. So your `vData[,-c(1:8)]` is returning all rows and columns 9 through 20, a 20K by 12 matrix. Not small.

### Transposition

You probably already know what `t()` does: transpose the matrix so that it is now 12 by 20K.

*A word of warning:* if all of your data.frame columns are of the same class (e.g., 'character', 'logical'), then all is fine. However, the fact that data.frames allow disparate types of data in different columns is not a feature shared by matrices. If one data.frame column is different than the others, they will be converted to the highest common format, e.g., `logical < integer < numeric < character`.

### Back to a `data.frame`

After you transpose it (which converts to a `matrix`), you convert back to a data.frame, which may or may not be necessary depending on how to intend to deal with the data later. For instance, if the row names are not meaningful, then it may not be that useful to convert into a data.frame. That's relatively immaterial, but I'm a fan of not over-converting things. I'm also a fan of using the simpler data structure, and matrices are typically faster than data.frames.

### Head

... merely gives you the top `n` *rows* of a data.frame or matrix. In your case, since you transposed it, it is now 20K columns wide, which may be a bit unwieldy on the command line.

### Alternatives

Based on what I provided earlier, perhaps you just want to look at the top few rows and first few columns? `dataExpr0[1:5,1:5]` will work, as will (identically) `head(dataExpr0[,1:5], n=5)`.

### More Questions?

I strongly encourage you to read more of the [*Hadleyverse*](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) and become a little more familiar with subsetting and basic data management. It is fundamental to using *R*, and StackOverflow is not always patient enough to answer baseline questions like this. This forum is best suited for those who have already done some research, read documentation and help pages, and tried some code, and only after that cannot figure out why it is not working. You provided some basic code with is good, but SO is not ideally suited to teach how to start with *R*.